# Wamp | MySQL Service is not available

Tags: mysql, wamp

I uninstalled Wamp Server by mistake, and now when I reinstall it there was .dll package not found issue, after I solved it, now MySQL Service is not available as in the screenshot.
[image: here]

**When I click on **"Install Service"** it shows "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)." message**

I'm using wamp to create databases, and now I have to create APIs and so on, when I log in to phpMyadmin MySql choice is not allowing me to log in, but if I check MariaDB it log in successfully..
[image: here2]

what is the differences between MySql and MariaDB choices?
And any advices about how I can solve it? or should I just ignore it and work with MariaDB?

Comment: `what is the differences between MySql and MariaDB`...is something probably best answered by a google search, you could have a long discussion about it. And whether any of the differences are relevant to you depends on what features/versions you might want to use - of course we know nothing about your requirements. But I would strongly advise you to use the same type of database as will be used in the environment where you want to deploy the live version of your website.

Comment: @Luuk I've tried it before and it's not working!

Comment: The error with code `0xc000007b`  has something to do with the other problem you already solved ("I reinstall it there was .dll package not found issue, after I solved it"), see: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,657012,657019#msg-657019

Comment: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-the-application-is-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b-error/

check this article, this seems common problem.. `so don't cry, give it a try`

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? If you are facing any problem with installing a service on Windows, is this even related to programming?

Comment: What version was running before? What version did you re-install?